# Get query result in Thoth.Json encodable format

Tags: f#, f#-data

Am trying to get a list of ids from a table as an array/list of integers, then encoding that with Thoth and outputting.

Function is

```
let listOfIds (columnId: int) =
    let ids = db.Query<int> $"Select id From table Where column = {columnId}"
    ids.ToArray //Tried AsList as well
```

Debugger shows the query is connect and the ids array is populated with the right values,, but when calling generates an exception at the encoder:

```
module PageController
let loadHomePage =   
    let ids = module.listOfIds 2
    Encode.Auto.toString(4, ids)
```

Exceptions:

```
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for '<StartupCode$WebApplication>.$PageController' threw an exception.
 ---> System.Exception: Cannot generate auto encoder for Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2[[Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Unit, FSharp.Core, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a],[System.Int32[], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]]. Please pass an extra encoder.
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Core.PrintfModule.PrintFormatToStringThenFail@1433.Invoke(String message) in F:\workspace\_work\1\s\src\fsharp\FSharp.Core\printf.fs:line 1433
   at Thoth.Json.Net.Encode.autoEncodeRecordsAndUnions(FSharpMap`2 extra, CaseStrategy caseStrategy, Boolean skipNullField, Type t)
   at Thoth.Json.Net.Encode.autoEncoder(FSharpMap`2 extra, CaseStrategy caseStrategy, Boolean skipNullField, Type t)
   at Thoth.Json.Net.Encode.Auto.generateEncoder[T](FSharpOption`1 caseStrategy, FSharpOption`1 extra, FSharpOption`1 skipNullField)
   at Thoth.Json.Net.Encode.Auto.toString[T](Int32 space, T value, FSharpOption`1 caseStrategy, FSharpOption`1 extra, FSharpOption`1 skipNullField)
   at <StartupCode$WebApplication>.$PageController..cctor() in C:\Users\dredgy\RiderProjects\WebApplication\WebApplication\PageController.fs:line 25
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at PageController.get_loadHomePage()
   at <StartupCode$WebApplication>.$Startup.Configure@25-1.Invoke(HttpContext context) in C:\Users\dredgy\RiderProjects\WebApplication\WebApplication\Startup.fs:line 26
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Comment: When your problem is an exception or error, a good practice is to paste the full text of that exception/error in the question body, so that whoever tries to answer doesn't have to guess.

Comment: Have added to the first post, is that the type doesn't want to be encoded.  It does work when using a custom type of `type x={id:int}` but since I just want a list of ids a la `[1, 2, 3]` that's not an ideal solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your `listOfIds` function doesn't return an array of numbers. It returns a function instead.

If you ask whatever IDE you're using what the type of `listOfIds` is, it will tell you something like this:

```
listOfIds : int -> (unit -> int array)
```

On the last line you apparently meant to call method `.ToArray()` on the result of the query, but instead you only *referenced* it, turning it into a function and returning as result of `listOfIds`. This function has type `unit -> int array`, so that's what the result of `listOfIds` itself becomes.

Then you're trying to pass that to `Encode.Auto.toString` (whatever that is), and it complains that it doesn't know how to encode an F# function:

```
Cannot generate auto encoder for Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc...
```

---

To fix, make sure you actually *call* the `ToArray` method by giving it the parameter. In this case (I can only assume, because I don't know what `db` is), the method has a single parameter of type `unit`, which is equivalent to "no parameters" in C#, so that's what you should pass:

```
let listOfIds (columnId: int) =
    let ids = db.Query<int> $"Select id From table Where column = {columnId}"
    ids.ToArray()
```

Comment: Goddammit. Cheers. Had to double check that wasn't a transcription error.